# Cannot get my multiple regex working for specific case in URL structure

Tags: php, regex, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I am trying to match regex for my URL structures below:

```
SPECIFIC CASE #1:
http://www.example.com/webapp/some-text.html
http://www.example.com/webapp/some-text-a1.html
http://www.example.com/webapp/some-a2-text.html

SPECIFIC CASE #2:
http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-vs-some-text.html
http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-a1-vs-sec-b2-text.html
http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-a1-vs-sec-b2-text-vs-third-c3-text.html
http://www.example.com/webapp/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1.html

SPECIFIC CASE #3:
http://www.example.com/webapp/sub-app/some-text-a1.html
```

My regex is:

```
SPECIFIC CASE #1:
\/webapp\/(.*)\.html

SPECIFIC CASE #3:
\/webapp\/sub-app\/(.*)\.html
```

Case #1 and #3 working. But for #2 it maches all including #1.

The thing is that my Web application is structured so If I visit the above example links some work and other gives me error 404.

I think my regex is wrong because I have multiple cases for that. Currently it is only working for specific case #1.

My guess is that my regex from above is not good for that. Do I need multuple regexes for that? Which one?

Is there a way for regex to check if value "vs" exists (one or multiple times) inside the given URL?

Any ideas or better solutions exist?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May I know what differs Case #2 from Case #1? Is it the `vs` keyword?

Comment: Exactly. The difference is the word "vs".
Currently I am trying to match "vs" inside url with this regex (?:^|\W)vs(?:$|\W) or any other?

Comment: \/webapp\/.*(?:^|\W)vs(?:$|\W)+.*html - is this regex ok?

Comment: Which regex should I use so that I could capture URl which has not got vs word inside?

Comment: Almost got it. ^((?!vs).*)+.html but i need /webapp/ before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
/\/webapp\/(.*)(-vs-.*)+\.html/
```

This regex matches any repetitive `-vs-.*` once or more.

Sample: https://3v4l.org/2gWlN

Comment: Thanks for solution that. It works! Brilliant!
Also, regex .*^((?!vs).*)+.html is missing /webapp/ before for URls non-containing word "vs". Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand.. :D

Comment: Sorry for bad english.
Your regex works for vs (repetitive) - that is excellent. 
I am wondering how can i target CASE #1 or URLs that does not have these "vs" in?
I have ^((?!vs).*)+.html but I am not sure if it is right because it is missing /webapp/ before.

Comment: So which means, you need single regex to match these three different set of URLs?

Comment: Yes, You are right.
Is that possible to make a single one?
I was thinking it should be simplified solution with few of them but, or I was wrong about it?

Comment: @Fritex can, but I'm not sure what's your use case? See this: https://3v4l.org/uhDUb

Comment: Ok, That works too. I am suprized.
I think i will need three regex-es. One that targets /sub-app/, second which already you provided and the third one which is actually missing.
For example if I have two URls and one of them two contains "vs" and another does not.
How could I target between both of them the one which does not contains "vs" (one or any eather)?

Comment: Basically I am missing regex that does not contains "vs" and is not part of "/sub-app/".

Comment: Is that regex like \/webapp\/.*(?!-vs-)+.html ?

Comment: Your "Specific Case #1" in your question, that one works right? You just need to know that #1 is the superset of #2, hence #2 should do the catching first, and let the leftovers be handled by #1, and #3.

Comment: Yes, exactly like You said.