# Need PHP regex to match pattern in URL

Tags: php, regex, url, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have problem with matching pattern in URL and getting the right result.

The URL example:

```
#1: http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-vs-some-text.html
#2: http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-a1-vs-sec-b2-text.html
#3: http://www.example.com/webapp/first-text-a1-vs-sec-b2-text-vs-third-c3-text.html
#4: http://www.example.com/webapp/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1.html
```

Result without -vs- (HINT: -vs- can be shown once or repetitive from above URLs):

```
#1: first-text and some-text
#2: first-text-a1 and sec-b2-text
#3: first-text-a1, sec-b2-text and third-c3-text
#4: some-text-1a, sec-text-b2, third-text and last-text-c1
```

Is there a way of PHP loop to do that?

There is a situation that -vs- in URL structure can be found once or multiple times.

Should I get my results with few patterns or can it be possible done with one pattern match?

Should I first split the given URL and then check for characters & symbols left or right of the -vs-?

Had You have that kind of situation ever?
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for help and sharing ideas to get final result!

Comment: What is the "right result"?

Comment: You are able to [retrieve strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439363/cannot-get-my-multiple-regex-working-for-specific-case-in-url-structure) and you want to separate substrings by “-vs-”, right? Use `explode( '-vs-', $string );`. Regex can't capture (as separated) repeating groups

Comment: Can't you just use str_replace?

Comment: Thanks for ideas. Will try with explode() and str_replace() to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex `([^\/.]+?)(?:-vs-|\.\w+$)` with `preg_match_all` to return the different parts before and after `-vs-`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU7bW8/1)

Comment: Any way to match given URL with slash / on ending instad of .html? Example: http://www.example.com/directory/some-text-a1-vs-sec-text-b2-vs-third-text-vs-last-text-c1/ . If I test regex for above URL, the 4th (third) match does not shown up.

Comment: @Fritex Add another condition in the non-capturing group like so: `([^\/.]+?)(?:-vs-|\.\w+$|\/$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU7bW8/2)